# Why does the URL http://a/%%30%30 crash Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security, url, browser, crash

The URL `http://a/%%30%30` crashes Google Chrome, even when just hovering over it.

Why does this happen?

Comment: https://crbug.com/533361 https://crrev.com/350086

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about a bug in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Tom Scott explains this in [his YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fw5Cyh21TE):

1. `http://a/%%30%30` is decoded as `http://a/%00` because `%30` is `0`
2. `http://a/%00` is then further decoded by another piece of code as `http://a/<NULL>` because `%00` is the NULL character

The bug was [originally demonstrated by Andris Atteka](http://andrisatteka.blogspot.in/2015/09/a-simple-string-to-crash-google-chrome.html) who simply added a null character to the string.

[image: URL ASCII table]

Comment: Too bad Tom Scott did not get any reward for reporting this bug.